# Bind A Record without IP

Tags: linux

How to create an A record without IP address. e.g.:

If i nslookup zen.spamhaus.org

output:

```
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8
Name:    zen.spamhaus.org
```

Here its not showing the IP address of zen.spamhaus.org

Comment: I'd think CNAME might be what you want.  Unfortunately, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

zen.spamhaus.org is a subdomain with no A record; there's a SOA and NS records for it, but no A record.

Comment: I've already tried to use only SOA and NS record but it did not work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish??

Answer (score 1):

When you use dig instead of nslookup you get some more information:

```
$ dig zen.spamhaus.org

; <<>> DiG 9.6.2-P2-RedHat-9.6.2-5.P2.fc12 <<>> zen.spamhaus.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21906
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;zen.spamhaus.org.      IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
zen.spamhaus.org.   150 IN  SOA need.to.know.only.hostmaster.spamhaus.org. 1007212045 3600 600 432000 150
```

For more information on how to create such subdomains please see [this HOWTO](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/subdomain.html).